# Relist rows of a data table in R following the structure of a desired list?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, datatable

I am loading a csv file into a data table in R that looks like the below:

| Name | Location | Dates.Start | Dates.End | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Virtual | 12/12/2022 | 13/12/2022 | ... |
| Anne | In person | 05/01/2023 | 06/01/2023 | ... |
| Ben | Hybrid | 10/01/2023 | 11/01/2023 | ... |

I need to iterate over each row and use it as a list with the following structure:

```
row_list = list(Name = 'John' ,
                Location = 'Virtual',
                Dates = data.frame(Start = '12/12/2022',
                                   End = '13/12/2022'),
                ...
               )
```

I have tried converting each row to a list and I can do it by iterating over all rows and creating the required entities.

```
for (row in nrow(dt)){
  row_list = list(Name = dt$Name[row] ,
                Location = dt$Location[row],
                Dates = data.frame(Start = dt$Dates.Start[row],
                                   End = dt$Dates.End[row]),
                ...
               )
}
```

The problem is that I have multiple columns in the original data table and I would prefer a relist command that would automatically identify and merge the columns that need to be stores as a data frame.
If I use the `list()` command the columns won't merge in a data frame (i.e. the 'Dates' data frame).
Is there a way to merge the two 'Dates' into one data frame while creating the list without needing to call each value separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this solution, first I prepare a list of columns `toDf` that must be bound in a data.frame. Then I get the list of other columns by difference (`setdiff`). The two sets then are merged into the `Cols` list.

```r
library(purrr)

toDf <- list(Dates = c("Dates.Start", "Dates.End"))
otherCols <- setdiff(names(dt), reduce(toDf, c))
Cols <- c(setNames(otherCols, otherCols), toDf)

Cols

$Name
[1] "Name"

$Location
[1] "Location"

$Dates
[1] "Dates.Start" "Dates.End"
```

Then by using `asplit` the data.frame is split by row and each row is processed according to elements of `Cols`. When there is an element containing two or more column names, the corresponding data is merged into a data.frame

```r
asplit(dt,1) |>
    map(~{
        data <- as.list(.x)
        map(Cols, ~if(length(.x) == 1)
                       data[[.x]]
                   else
                       data.frame(data[.x]))
    })
    
##> [[1]]
##> [[1]]$Name
##> [1] "John"
##> 
##> [[1]]$Location
##> [1] "Virtual"
##> 
##> [[1]]$Dates
##>   Dates.Start  Dates.End
##> 1  12/12/2022 13/12/2022
##> 
##> 
##> [[2]]
##> [[2]]$Name
##> [1] "Anne"
##> 
##> [[2]]$Location
##> [1] "In person"
##> 
##> [[2]]$Dates
##>   Dates.Start  Dates.End
##> 1  05/01/2023 06/01/2023
##> 
##> 
##> [[3]]
##> [[3]]$Name
##> [1] "Ben"
##> 
##> [[3]]$Location
##> [1] "Hybrid"
##> 
##> [[3]]$Dates
##>   Dates.Start  Dates.End
##> 1  10/01/2023 11/01/2023
```

An alternative equivalent *by column* solution can be:

```r
map(Cols, ~if(length(.x) == 1)
               dt[[.x]]
           else
               split(dt[.x], ~ I(1:nrow(dt)))) |>
    transpose()
```